# How to disconnect active call with CallKit?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am making an app with CallKit support with WebRTC. I could not find a way to disconnect active call in CallKitUI, Once I accepted the incoming call from answer button even though the call is disconnected from peer connection.

Comment: try this (not test) `func end(call: Call) {
  // 1.
  let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call.uuid)
  // 2.
  let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)
  
  requestTransaction(transaction)
}

// 3.
private func requestTransaction(_ transaction: CXTransaction) {
  callController.request(transaction) { error in
    if let error = error {
      print("Error requesting transaction: \(error)")
    } else {
      print("Requested transaction successfully")
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks Quoc Nguyen, I will try